# Android ScrollView: Scrolling out of display

Tags: android

I have a HorizontalScrollView which contains a TextView with a long text. The ScrollView is scrolled programmatically from right to left to the end of the TextView's text so that the end is displayed at the right edge of the phones display.

Is it possible to scroll the text even further so that it scrolls out of the left side of the phones display?

Comment: You mean you want to continue scrolling after the end of the text? Just put a padding on the `ScrollView`.

Comment: @XaverKapeller Thanks for commenting so fast! Can you describe that a little bit more with the padding?

Comment: I will write a proper answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To continue scrolling after the end of the text has been reached you can apply a padding to the `TextView` like this:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/text"
            android:paddingRight="50dp"/>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

The value of the padding determines how far you continue scroll past the end of the text. 50dp is about the size of a finger on the screen of the device.

Comment: When I add padding like this the only thing that happens is that the text starts to appear 50dp away from the right edge of the display.